# Set port number for the embedded h2 database

Tags: spring, heroku, h2

I use `h2` in-memory database only for the testing purposes. The default port seems to be `8082`, which causes my tests to fail on heroku.

I want to change this port number. How can I do that ?

What I've done so far:

1. There seems to be a file on my local machine (`$USER_HOME/.h2.server.properties`) that specifies this port. Let alone it is very strange to have that file outside of the application workspace, I cannot check it in heroku.
2. I tried to set `webPort`, `port` in `application-test.properties` (it is a properties file I use for my tests) but it didn't work (I tried different combinations `server.port`, `spring.data.source.h2.webPort, etc.)

**application-test.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:tesdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

test{

    forkEvery = 1
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}

repositories {
     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version:'5.1.44'
    compile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version:'3.18.0-GA'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2', version:'2.0.14.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version:'0.7.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-cas', version:'4.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-acl', version:'4.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'bsf', name: 'bsf', version:'2.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-batch', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-ldap', version:'4.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'javax.jdo', name: 'jdo-api', version:'3.0.1'
    compile group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-core', version:'4.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'springloaded', version:'1.2.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib', version:'1.0.6'
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version:'2.11.0'
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version:'1.6'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version:'2.5'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jersey', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version:'0.7.5'
    compile(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version:'4.5.3') {
exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version:'3.4'
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE') {
exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate', name: 'jetty-all', version:'9.2.13.v20150730'
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version:'1.4.196'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-test', version:'4.3.12.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version:'4.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-core', version:'1.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.sleepycat', name: 'je', version:'5.0.73'
    compile group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version:'1.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:'4.3.12.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version:'1.13.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.hateoas', name: 'spring-hateoas', version:'0.23.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-rest-core', version:'2.6.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.plugin', name: 'spring-plugin-core', version:'1.2.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version:'4.3.12.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.11'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version:'4.3.12.RELEASE'
}
```

Comment: The JDBC-URL can contain a connection-string that neither require any socket nor any port. That makes it perfect for testing purposes. Please give a example of your jdbc-connection-url.

Comment: How are you starting the h2 server? If you don't need to connect to the database from another application why are you even starting a tcp server? What is the rest of your database related configuration?

Comment: `8082` is the port used by h2console webServer. Spring boot doesn't use it. You either have a bean which starts it or start it yourself somewhere with `Server.createWebServer` you need to find where it happens disable it. Changing the port won't help you, you can only use one port on heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Earlier, I created a base class for my tests, where I create my H2 server. The port was set in the same class.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void init() throws SQLException {
    webServer = Server.createWebServer("-web", "-webAllowOthers", "-webPort", "8082");
    webServer.start();
}
```

But changing the port doesn't solve the problem. I found out that in contrary to how eclipse runs each test separately, heroku runs all of them once, so the server doesn't get destroyed and is kept alive between two tests. Therefore I have to kill the server after each test class is finished running:

```
@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() throws SQLException {
    webServer.stop();
}
```

Comment: They are end-to-end tests.

Comment: Is there a way to change the web console port using the properties file?