# H2db jar not working on port other than 8082

Tags: java, port, h2, h2db

I have a h2db jar which i want to run on port other than 8082.

I tried `java -jar -Dserver.port=XXXX` but it is still running on 8082.

Is there any way to run it on other port?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set port number for the embedded h2 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587960/set-port-number-for-the-embedded-h2-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
java -jar h2-*.jar -webPort 9999
```

where `h2-*.jar` is the name of H2's jar file and `9999` is a port number.

There are also `-tcpPort`, `-pgPort` and other parameters.

If you want to start the web server only without other open ports for JDBC and ODBC clients and open a browser window, use

```
java -jar h2-*.jar -web -webPort 9999 -browser
```

Comment: it worked, you can upvote question if you think it can help others

Answer (score 1):

I think the parameter to be used is `webPort` and not `server.port`.

Also you might have to provide this parameter in the `.h2.server.properties` file as stated in the documentation:

http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#console_settings

Comment: i am not dealing with the code. i just downloaded the jar and want to run at diff port number with some arguement like -Dserver.port=XXXX